# Numbers in a Fixed Ratio with Same Multiset of Digits

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory

Recently I'm thinking of a problem of “magic simplifying of fractions”. Specifically, we can simplify “19/95” to “1/5” as we can “factor” or “cancel” out the “9”. Now I am consider the fraction of “1x/5x” and we just “factor out” the “x”. I am curious that what are the number of such number. Specifically, We want to find out how many integers $x,y$ such that:

(1) $x/y$ is a given ratio $p/q$.

(2) both $x$ and $y$ are $n$-digit (we allow leading zeroes).

(3) If we consider $x$ and $y$'s digits
as a multiset, they are equal. For example, $110$ and $101$ both correspond to the multiset $\{0,1^2\}$ and they are equal.

My attempt currently we can allow $O(c^n)$ such numbers for some $c>0$. For example, for ratio $1/5$, notice that $142857/714285$ is $1/5$ and we can consider $x$ to be a number containing $n/7$ zeros and $n/7$ sequences of $142857$. Therefore the number of such numbers is $2^{(2n/7)}/\mathrm{poly}(n)$.

Now my question is, is it correct you have $10^n/\mathrm{poly}(n)$ such number pairs for all ratios $p/q$? I guess it is correct since, if $x$ is “random” then $y$ is “as random as” $x$. And two random $n$-digit number happen to have the same multiset of digits is of probability $1/\mathrm{poly}(n)$.

Answer (score -1):

For $2$ digits ...

There are $100$ possible candidate pairs. The pairs of interest will be a subset of this.

$\frac{10x + y}{10a + b}$ such that if $x = p \wedge a = q$ (only $1$ of $4$ possibilities) then $\frac{10x + y}{10a + b} = \frac{x}{a} = \frac{p}{q}$ and $y = b$. We're interested in $\frac{p}{q}$

$\frac{10x + b}{10a + b} = \frac{x}{a} \implies 10ax + ab = 10ax + bx \implies ab = bx \implies a = x$

The "obvious" pairs are then fractions like $\frac{23}{23} = \frac{2}{2} = 1$. There are $99$ of them as $\frac{00}{00}$ is undefined.

Comment: Oh, what I mean for fixed ratio $p/q$ is that for a "given" $p/q$... Of course $p=q=1$  is trivial though

Comment: Also two digits there are nontrivial pairs too, one of them is $19/95$ as in the problem, the others are $16/64$ and $26/65$. Of course, as the digits goes bigger there are more and more nontrivial pairs too.

Comment: Ah! "Trivial" , that's the apposite term. The problem as far as finding some kinda "formula"  is that you're only allowed *valid moves* to find out how *invalid moves* lead to the correct answer. *Asambhav* (impossible)?

Comment: Not sure what the valid and invalid moves here means... Originally, you can make the remaining terms on their corresponding locations (such as $1142857/2285714$), not exactly need do be disocated (and of course, you can also make the remaining terms not on their corresponding locations too). However, now in the problem statement, to simplify the problem, it only consider the case that the ''cancelled'' remaining digits are at the end, so that's what I need if I make equal digit multiset for $x$ and $y$ because we can attach $p$ to $x$ and $q$ to $y$ though.

Comment: Also, I apologize that when I was replying you with examples of $19/95$, I was thought about the original one that you can delete the digits anywhere, but I forgot the problem has restricted that the deleted digits has to be at the end. Yes, you are correct that for two digits the cases must have $(x,y)$ is a divisor of $18$ (like $5/6$ has example of $45/54$) and $p+q$ is a multiple of $11$ or $p=q=1$, but for a given $p/q$ search for $x,y$, for example, $1/2$, ah... It's hard to find general ones that fits this.

Comment: Interesting idea you have there. I  hope you get to the bottom of this mystery. If we could *identify* such fractions, it would make life so much the easier for students and professors alike. Just imagine if $\frac{38579}{17958} = 3$!!